# Get Select Value On Document Ready As Well As On Change

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of a dropdown select element (within a form) on page load as well as on change and pass it to another input (hidden). Here are the code I have tried so far.

This one works on page load, but now working when changed:

```
        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        var comment_post_ID = jQuery("#alldentists").val();
            jQuery("#comment_post_ID").val( comment_post_ID );
        });
```

This doesn't work on pageload but working on changing the select options.

```
        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

            jQuery( "#alldentists" ).change(function() {
                var comment_post_ID = jQuery("#alldentists").val();

            });
            jQuery("#comment_post_ID").val( comment_post_ID );
        });
```

Is there any way I can get the value on both pageload as well as on change? I am using jQuery 1.11.0.

Comment: I'm guessing this `var comment_post_ID` limits the scope of the variable, making it available only within the `.change()` function. Try declaring it outside with empty values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare variable **"comment_post_ID"** globally.

```
  <select name="alldentists" id="alldentists"><option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="comment_post_ID"/> 

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var comment_post_ID=jQuery("#alldentists").val();
      jQuery("#alldentists").on('change', function(e) {
        comment_post_ID = jQuery("#alldentists").val();
        jQuery("#comment_post_ID").val(comment_post_ID);  
      });
      jQuery("#comment_post_ID").val(comment_post_ID);
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/3PPvH/1/